# Elasticsearch - query exact value in array so that documents containing that value+others are not returned

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a query to search for a value that will return only the documents that have that exact value (even if repeated in the array) and no other documents (even if there's 1 entry of the value in the array). So, `"bar" : [ "A", "A"]`  would be eligible but not `"bar" : [ "A", "B"]`

Example of a dataset:

```
"loren" : [
  {
    "id" : "1", 
    "foo": [{"bar": "A"},{"bar": "A"}]
  },
  {
    "id" : "2", 
    "foo": [{"bar": "A"},{"bar": "B"}]
  },
]
```

Example of the output I would expect:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.3666863,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "loren",
            "_type": "loren",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.3666863,
            "_source": {
                "foo": [
                    {
                        "bar": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "bar": "A"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kamal thank you for the enlightening. That lead me to the answer I think... but let me know your thoughts.

When filtering the arrays, looks like by doing `doc['foo.bar'].size();`, elasticsearch makes a `count(distinct ...)` sql-equivalent and returns size `n` for arrays with `n` distinct values.

working query example:

```
GET /loren/_search 
{
   "_source":[
      "foo.bar"
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "foo.bar":"A"
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{
            "script":{
               "script":{
                  "source":"1==doc['foo.bar'].size();",
                  "lang":"painless"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was wondering why my solution wasn't working in your machine `Bummer :(`. After the discussion we've had, the solution I've tried still worked as expected. `:(` 

Notice that my solution checks for word called `test`. If you look at it, it checks the word `test` which I've passed in `params.token`. Did you change this value `test` to `SMT` or `DU` and gave it a try. I'm sure it would be working as expected.

Comment: `{
                        "source" : """
                          List myList = doc['functions.brandCode.keyword'];
                          int size = myList.size();
                          int count = Collections.frequency(myList,params.token);
                          if(count==size)
                            return true;
                          """,
                        "lang"   : "painless",
                        "params": {
                          "token": "SMT"
                        }
 }`

Comment: Regardless, your solutions looks good :-). Go ahead and accept it, but do upvote my answer if you haven't ;-). And do let me know if you still have any queries.

Comment: I tried your solution and even making some little tweaks to it but it didn't work as expected. I've upvoted your answer because it actually helped a lot. Thank you, you're very kind!

Comment: Well, in the end, I'm glad you got your solution!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the below [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-script-query.html) for what you are looking for.

Note that the field `bar` should be of type `keyword`.

```
POST <your_search_index>/_search
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source" : """
                          List myList = doc['bar'];
                          int size = myList.size();
                          int count = Collections.frequency(myList,params.token);
                          if(count==size)
                            return true;
                          """,
                        "lang"   : "painless",
                        "params": {
                          "token": "test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you would get in the response is list of documents with the field `bar` having only `test` as its value/values.

Note that if your mapping is created dynamically, you can try with `bar.keyword` in the above query.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: thank you for trying to help, I've tried that approach but it didn't work as expected. Also I think that using a query directly would have better performance. Here's is an example of a dataset and query using oracle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd338/5). The problem is that I don't have enough knowledge regarding elasticsearch to convert that example, can you help?

Comment: Sure, but could you please post what you've observed in results and what you were expecting. Looking at your question, the above query works correctly. Meanwhile I'll check the link.

Comment: @bsferreira The link you've mentioned has multiple joins, which won't work in ES. Could you post your mapping details how your index looks like, I can probably create a query based on your mapping details similar to the link you've mentioned.

Comment: @bsferreira hey I am in that link. Sorry I've had some work earlier. let me know once you see my messages I've sent in that link.